# R - Vectorized implementation of ternary function

Tags: r, vectorization

I have three vectors `X`, `Y` and `Z` of equal length `n`. I need to create an `n x n x n` array of a function `f(X[i],Y[j],Z[k])`. The straightforward way to do this is to sequentially loop through each element of each of the 3 vectors. However, the time required to compute the array grows exponentially with `n`. Is there a way to implement this using vectorized operations?

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, I have added a simple example of what's needed.

```
set.seed(1)
X = rnorm(10)
Y = seq(11,20)
Z = seq(21,30)

F = array(0, dim=c( length(X),length(Y),length(Z) ) )
for (i in 1:length(X))
  for (j in 1:length(Y))
    for (k in 1:length(Z))
      F[i,j,k] = X[i] * (Y[j] + Z[k])
```

Thanks.

Comment: A reproducible example could be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use nested `outer` :

```
set.seed(1)
X = rnorm(10)
Y = seq(11,20)
Z = seq(21,30)

F = array(0, dim = c( length(X),length(Y),length(Z) ) )
for (i in 1:length(X))
  for (j in 1:length(Y))
    for (k in 1:length(Z))
      F[i,j,k] = X[i] * (Y[j] + Z[k])

F2 <- outer(X, outer(Y, Z, "+"), "*")

> identical(F, F2)
[1] TRUE
```

A microbenchmark including the `expand.grid` solution proposed by Nick K :

```
X = rnorm(100)
Y = seq(1:100)
Z = seq(101:200)

forLoop <- function(X, Y, Z) {
  F = array(0, dim = c( length(X),length(Y),length(Z) ) )
  for (i in 1:length(X))
    for (j in 1:length(Y))
      for (k in 1:length(Z))
        F[i,j,k] = X[i] * (Y[j] + Z[k])
  return(F)
}

nestedOuter <- function(X, Y, Z) {
  outer(X, outer(Y, Z, "+"), "*")
}

expandGrid <- function(X, Y, Z) {
  df <- expand.grid(X = X, Y = Y, Z = Z)
  G <- df$X * (df$Y + df$Z)
  dim(G) <- c(length(X), length(Y), length(Z))
  return(G)
}

library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  forLoop = F1 <- forLoop(X, Y, Z), 
  nestedOuter = F2 <- nestedOuter(X, Y, Z), 
  expandGrid = F3 <- expandGrid(X, Y, Z), 
  times = 50L)

> mbm
Unit: milliseconds
expr         min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
forLoop 3261.872552 3339.37383 3458.812265 3388.721159 3524.651971 4074.40422    50
nestedOuter    3.293461    3.36810    9.874336    3.541637    5.126789   54.24087    50
expandGrid   53.907789   57.15647   85.612048   88.286431  103.516819  235.45443    50
```

Comment: Good answer, though it doesn't generalise to an arbitrary ternary function f(X, Y, Z)

Comment: But as you've just pointed out it's a lot faster than using expand.grid!

Comment: Thanks. This is substantially faster, but can it be generalized as per Nick K's comment above? The function in my code is more complicated than in the example given. Specifically, it is `F[i,j,k] = X[i] + c1*X[i]*c2 + X[i]*sqrt(V[j]*c2)*Z[k]`, where `c1` and `c2` are arbitrary constants. This can be easily implemented using Nick K's `expand.grid` method.

Comment: `outer(X, outer(sqrt(Y * c2), Z, "*"), function(a, b) a + a * c1 * c2 + a * b)` though the expand.grid method is clearer

Comment: You can use anonymous functions in `outer`, but yes maybe using simply vectorisation over an expanded grid is the best solution

Answer (score 5):

Here's as an additional option, a possible Rcpp implementation (in case you like your loops). I wasn't able to outperform @Juliens solution though (maybe someone can), but they are more or less have the same timing

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector RCPP(NumericVector X,  NumericVector Y, NumericVector Z){

             int nrow = X.size(), ncol = 3, indx = 0;
             double temp(1) ;
             NumericVector out(pow(nrow, ncol)) ;
             IntegerVector dim(ncol) ;

             for (int l = 0; l < ncol; l++){
               dim[l] = nrow;
             }             

            for (int j = 0; j < nrow; j++) {
               for (int k = 0; k < nrow; k++) {
                     temp = Y[j] + Z[k] ;
                   for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
                         out[indx] = X[i] * temp ;
                         indx += 1 ;
                   }
               }
            }

            out.attr("dim") = dim;
            return out;
}')
```

**Validating**

```
identical(RCPP(X, Y, Z), F)
## [1] TRUE
```

**A quick benchmark**

```
set.seed(123)
X = rnorm(100)
Y = 1:100
Z = 101:200

nestedOuter <- function(X, Y, Z) outer(X, outer(Y, Z, "+"), "*")

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( 
  nestedOuter = nestedOuter(X, Y, Z),  
  RCPP = RCPP(X, Y, Z),
  unit = "relative",
  times = 1e4)

# Unit: relative
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# nestedOuter 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000 10000
#        RCPP 1.164254 1.141713 1.081235 1.100596 1.080133 0.7092394 10000
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use expand.grid as follows:

```
df <- expand.grid(X = X, Y = Y, Z = Z)
G <- df$X * (df$Y + df$Z)
dim(G) <- c(length(X), length(Y), length(Z))
all.equal(F, G)
```

If you had a vectorised function, this would work just as well. If not, you could use plyr::daply.